# setAttribute the only option to set list = <id datalist> in input element?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, setattribute, html-datalist

I cannot set the `list` property of an `<input>` element. `sel.list = id` is not working in my code.

```
var sel = document.createElement("input");
sel.type = "text";
sel.id = "inputSelectName";
sel.list = "inputNamesList"; // Does not work.
//sel.setAttribute("list", "inputNamesList"); // Works
sel.name = "name"; // FIXME: We should reconsider the name name...
frm.appendChild(sel);

var datl = document.createElement("datalist");
datl.id = "inputNamesList";
// Populating the dataList
frm.appendChild(datl);
```

Of course, this doesn't work because the `list` attribute is not the `list = {id for datalist}` that I want. The only way to make this work is with the `setAttribute` method.

How can I solve this without using the setter, but by changing the attribute directly?

When I look in the developer tools, I see that `setAttribute("list", id)` is not setting the `list` attribute.

Comment: @DavidThomas, [the list attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-input-list).

Comment: @zzzzBov: indeed: [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input).

Comment: Why do you want to solve it without setter?
What's wrong with `setAttribute` ?

Comment: whoa, edit your question no one can understand what you just posted as a comment...

Comment: Ok. You can not change it directly for now.
It is element interface:
http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element

Comment: One can set the list attribute. But sel.list seems to be something different in my code.
By using setAttribute list = null and setAttribute changes the outerHTML.

Comment: @JorisSpekreijse—yes, there is a distinct difference between a DOM property and an HTML attribute. Some properties and attributes always reflect each other, some don't, and there are differences between browsers.